# how to fetch the array data from database query in a php file to ajax sucess data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

i am trying to get the data which is in array, from an SQL query to the ajax success data. Here is the code i tried,

```
function adminchecksub(value1){
//alert('hi');
var value1=$('#adminsid').val();
//alert(value1);
if(value1==''){
alert('Please enter a Sub id');
}
else{
//alert(value1);
 $.ajax({

                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: root_url + '/services/services.php?method=adminsubcheck',
                                        data: {value1:value1},
                                        async: true,
                                        success: function (data) {
                                                alert(data);

                                                if (data == 1) {
                                                        alert('inside');
                                                        //window.location.assign(rdurl+"?sid="+sid);
                                                        return true;
                                                } else {
                                                        //alert('does not exist!');
                                                       //alert('outside');
                                                        return false;
                                                }

                                        }
                                });
}
```

now in the php method which is requested from the above ajax call, i have to get the data return by this function which is returning an array

```
   function adminsubcheck($sid){
$subid=$sid['value1'];
$row = array();
//echo $subid;
$query = "SELECT Sub_id,Status,Sub_type FROM Sub WHERE Sub_id=$subid";        
        //echo $query;
        //echo $subid;
        $queryresult = mysql_query($query);
        $count  = mysql_num_rows($queryresult);
         //echo $count;

         while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {

           $row[] = $r;
        } 
        return $row;

}
```

here $row is returning an array as data to the ajax function, where i need to get all the items seperately. Some one help me out to get the values into the ajax call. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP file, you can return your array as a json object in the following way (notice how the PHP file echos the result to pass it back to javascript)

```
...
$json = json_encode($row);
echo $json
```

Now add the following to your javascrip ajax

```
 $.ajax({

...
 // Whatever code you currently have
...

}).done(function ( json ) {

    var data = JSON.parse(json);

    //Continue with javascript
});
```

You can handle the java script variable 'data' as an associative array like it was in PHP

also, look how you populate the php variable $row and adjust the following way:

```
$cnt = 0;
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {

        $row[$cnt] = $r;
        $cnt++;

} 
 $json = json_encode($row);
    echo $json;
```

in javascript you can access your rows the following way in teh data variable:

```
var value = data[0]['field_name'];
```

in the above statement, 0 will correspond to the value of $cnt (i.e. mysql returned row number)

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ANSWERS IT REALLY HELPED ME, BUT I WANT TO GET THE VALUES FROM THE DATA , I TRIED LIKE THIS, THAT I GET THOSE VALUES INTO THE JS VARIABLES, BUT NEED TO DO THIS AS:
success: function (data){
var value2=data['sub_type'];
var value3=data['status'];
if (value2 == "PTC" && value3!=""){
alert(value2);
alert(value3);
window.location.assign(root_url+"/public/'+value2'/id="+value1);
return true;
} 
this is taking me to "public/'+value2'/id=30 "
here value2 is not printed as PTC how can i get those values into the url

Comment: in PHP, look how you are populating the variable $row,  i'm updating my answer now to help explain

Comment: please give any suggestion so that the values which i got from the data to ajax to be assigned to variables so that i need to relocate the page using window.location.assign('using these values')

Comment: I don't quite understand the question...?

Comment: thanks for the help i got the required thing, i'll ask u if i got any more doubts regarding further process thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $row;
```

replace like this

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

and add dataType='json' in ajax like this

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the value in ajax call i think it shoul be :

```
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
       $row[] = $r;
    }

    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$row));
    exit;
```